# How to use group to group categorical column pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe, A, which looks like this:

```
col1    col2
 1       low
 1       low
 1       high
 2       low
 2       high
```

Now, I want to group this dataframe on `col1`, while getting the count of every element in `col2` in a separate column. So, the resulting dataframe, B, should look like this:

```
 col1     low    high
  1        2       1
  2        1       1
```

I am trying to do this by using `group_by`, however this is not working. Anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my try using `value_counts` -> `reset_index` -> `pivot` -> `apply` (`dropna`) -> `astype(int)`

```
df2.value_counts().reset_index().pivot(columns='col2',values=0).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values)).astype(int)
```